# How can i play a word in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm currently working an app that can able to read the text (i.e the text shoud play as a sound) which i given in a txt file. Is it possible in android ?

Comment: You want to google `text-to-speech`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android there is a dedicated **API** for TextToSpeech (TTS in short) functionality.
You can easily use it to play text from a file or on the fly.

Here is the documentations page : [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Also checkout this tutorial for an example : [TTS Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, Even if this is a simple but basically am a beginner for android

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the built-in [Text-to-Speech (TTS) package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/package-summary.html) (more details [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)).